# Use of the Bonferroni correction

Tags: statistics

I am conducting an analysis of survey data.

I have carried out sign tests comparing the answers provided by two different groups to each question. There are several questions for which I am making this analysis.

Am I right in thinking that I do not need to use a Bonferroni (or any other type) of correction?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Better on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Deepak. A call perhaps 'better' made by someone who has participated actively in the 'statistics' tag.

Comment: @BruceET. Thanks. Does the instance below change anything?  am currently analysing survey data.One of the questions is how two different types of product would impact on a company across multiple parameters (sales, customer relations etc) I have conducted sign tests to compare the two different types of product for each of the parameter (But not across different parameters.

Comment: Should I be correcting for the multiple tests? On one hand, the tests are to be considered individually for each parameter, but on the other hand there is an implicit 'overall hypothesis' that one product type has a more positive impact on all the parameters.

Comment: If you are looking at the tests one at a time, then there is no need for the Bonferroni correction. If you are looking at several significant test results in conjunction to discuss an 'overall picture', then use the correction.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made $k$ confidence intervals (CIs) at the 95% level and wish to
use them in conjunction in order to get the overall picture of your data,
then the Bonferroni correction would be to make all of these CIs at the
level $100\% - 5\%/k.$ According to Bonferroni's Inequality for probabilities,
the overall 'error rate' of the $k$ CIs cannot exceed 5%. The Bonferroni
procedure for CIs is a little too aggressive (in the sense that it can
'over-correct'), but this effect is usually not important for a small (e.g.
5% overall rate, and a small $k$).

Similar advice holds for testing $k$ related hypotheses. The overall or
'family' significance level for $k$ hypotheses considered together
does not exceed 5% if the individual hypotheses are all significant
at level $5\%/k.$

Perhaps this kind of comparison occurs most often in the context of an
analysis of variance where a factor with $g$ levels is significant at
level $\alpha.$ Then to assess the overall pattern of significant
differences for the $k = {g \choose 2}$ pairwise comparisions, some
sort of 'correction' is needed in order to keep the 'family' type I
error rate under reasonable control.

Particularly when all $g$ levels
have the same number of replications and the same variance, there
are very many possible competitors to the Bonferroni method of
controlling the 'family' significance level. Some of the possibilities
are 'Fisher LSD', 'Tukey HSD', 'SNK', and 'Duncan'. Which one to use
depends on the experimental design, how many comparisons are being
made, and exactly what you mean by 'family error rate'.

You do not give enough information about your overall experimental
design for me to recommend a specific one of these possible methods
of controlling the family error rate for $k$ paired comparisons. 
Although the Bonferroni method can be too 'conservative' (overall
power too low), it is also among the most generally applicable method,
not to mention the simplicity of computation. [For example, in R statistical
software, the (Welsh)
procedure for a one-way ANOVA on levels that may have diverse variances,
uses the Bonferroni method as the default multiple-comparison method.]